# Getting message AH00558: apache2:

Tags: apache, ubuntu

```
Restarting web server apache2
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1.
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I am a newby installing Ubuntu Can someone help on the commands I need to set this up? I already tried `vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and adding localhost but I am still getting message when I restart Apache2 server.

Answer (score 11):

Fast but not so elegant solution:

Navigate to the file - apache2.conf, i would use a terminal, here the steps:

1. **cd /etc/apache2/**

   2.**vim apache2.conf** ( or **pluma apache2.conf**, if you are not a vi-geek )
2. Write on the bottom:

   - **ServerName localhost**
3. Save the file and restart apache, 
   with following commands in the terminal:

   - **/etc/init.d/apache2 restart**
     You **can use some UI** or other commands like "**service apache2 restart**".

Just for the case, you can make a **check**, to see ether **this directive** **isn't just disabled** in some of the configuration files:

- ***grep -inRH "ServerName " /etc/apache2/ | grep  "\s*#"***

Now the error is gone. You need root-rights for all this steps or use "sudo" instead.

*Hope i could help you. Cheers*.

Answer (score 6):

Run the following command:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

to determine path to your `httpd.conf` configuration file, then edit that file and uncomment (or add) line which should specify value for `ServerName` option, e.g.

```
ServerName localhost
```

For the web server, use the registered DNS name (e.g. `example.com`).

> If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.

Then restart your Apache as usual, e.g. `apachectl graceful`.

Answer (score 1):

Add below tag in your configuration file and try

ServerName localhost

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's always good to elaborate your answers, for e.g in this case where to add exactly in the configuration file, how this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your can use the commands for errors and which services are running.
I'll try using journalctl -u httpd.service and check if it's there based on the results. I know this was just a quick example in the localhost case and it works. But we all know that less experienced users can take advice literally and end up with, say, a sub-optimal or dangerous setting. This must always be remembered, therefore use the following: the ServerName directive allows your to use different domain names `localhost user-desktop 127.0.0.1 127.0.1.1` without errors for /etc/apache2/apache2.conf after the line # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet at the end of the file.

```
sudo journalctl -u apache2.service --since today --no-pager
sudo journalctl -u httpd.service --since today --no-pager
sudo systemctl status apache2.service -l --no-pager
sudo systemctl status httpd.service -l --no-pager
sudo tail -10 /var/log/apache2/access.log
sudo tail -10 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```